# Issue with using map on a array within a JSON response

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good day, I'm currently programming a react.js application that gets a JSON list of countries structured like the one below, all within an array

```
{
   "name":"Afghanistan",
   "topLevelDomain":[
      ".af"
   ],
   "alpha2Code":"AF",
   "alpha3Code":"AFG",
   "callingCodes":[
      "93"
   ],
   "capital":"Kabul",
   "altSpellings":[
      "AF",
      "Afġānistān"
   ],
   "region":"Asia",
   "subregion":"Southern Asia",
   "population":27657145,
   "latlng":[
      33.0,
      65.0
   ],
   "demonym":"Afghan",
   "area":652230.0,
   "gini":27.8,
   "timezones":[
      "UTC+04:30"
   ],
   "borders":[
      "IRN",
      "PAK",
      "TKM",
      "UZB",
      "TJK",
      "CHN"
   ],
   "nativeName":"افغانستان",
   "numericCode":"004",
   "currencies":[
      {
         "code":"AFN",
         "name":"Afghan afghani",
         "symbol":"؋"
      }
   ],
   "languages":[
      {
         "iso639_1":"ps",
         "iso639_2":"pus",
         "name":"Pashto",
         "nativeName":"پښتو"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am using .map to extract each country from the array but whenever i try to use .map to access 'languages' it throws the error
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`
I used the code `item.languages.map`, `item['languages'].map` and even `countries[0]['languages'].map` all of them returning the same error. Whenever i `console.log(item.languages)` it returns `[
      {
         "iso639_1":"ps",
         "iso639_2":"pus",
         "name":"Pashto",
         "nativeName":"پښتو"
      }
   ]`

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox with minimal reproducible code?

Comment: How are you processing individual / extracted items? Are you using a loop?

Comment: From interest would be the supplied function/lambda within your `map` function. You may messed up the parameters or something similar, I fall for stuff like that quite often as well.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments; As i was creating the codesandbox i noticed i had ```const [countries, setCountries] = useState([{}])``` which i then used setCountries(JSON), it must have messed the formatting up because when i removed {} it is now functioning

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should post your code snippet on how you are using the JSON. See this code snippet, running `item.languages.map` outputs to the console as what would be normal.

```js
const item = {
   "name":"Afghanistan",
   "topLevelDomain":[
      ".af"
   ],
   "alpha2Code":"AF",
   "alpha3Code":"AFG",
   "callingCodes":[
      "93"
   ],
   "capital":"Kabul",
   "altSpellings":[
      "AF",
      "Afġānistān"
   ],
   "region":"Asia",
   "subregion":"Southern Asia",
   "population":27657145,
   "latlng":[
      33.0,
      65.0
   ],
   "demonym":"Afghan",
   "area":652230.0,
   "gini":27.8,
   "timezones":[
      "UTC+04:30"
   ],
   "borders":[
      "IRN",
      "PAK",
      "TKM",
      "UZB",
      "TJK",
      "CHN"
   ],
   "nativeName":"افغانستان",
   "numericCode":"004",
   "currencies":[
      {
         "code":"AFN",
         "name":"Afghan afghani",
         "symbol":"؋"
      }
   ],
   "languages":[
      {
         "iso639_1":"ps",
         "iso639_2":"pus",
         "name":"Pashto",
         "nativeName":"پښتو"
      }
   ]
}

console.log({ languages: item.languages.map(l => l) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace arr with your array name.

I was able to access it. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-tdd-ewpbu?file=/src/App.js:881-937

```
arr.map(item => (
console.log(item.languages[0].name)
))
```